# Getting the DataKey Value in ASP.NET GridView on Button command event

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, datarow, datakey

Gridview is configured:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gvApptList" runat="server" CssClass="fullwidth" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="AppointmentID">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Designer" HeaderText="Designer" SortExpression="Designer" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="AppointmentDTM" HeaderText="Appointment Date" SortExpression="AppointmentDTM" DataFormatString="{0:MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm tt}" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="Status" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Disposition" HeaderText="Disposition" SortExpression="Disposition" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="AppointmentNotes" HeaderText="Appointment Notes" SortExpression="AppointmentNotes" />
                    <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" CommandName="viewAppointment" Text="View" />
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

When I click the "View" button, the gvApptList_RowCommand fires off.  COde for it is:

```
If e.CommandName = "viewAppointment" Then
        Dim tApptID As Long
        gvApptList.SelectedIndex = e.CommandArgument
        If IsNumeric(gvApptList.DataKeys(e.CommandArgument).Value) Then
            tApptID = gvApptList.SelectedDataKey.Value
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
        tbAppointmentID.Text = tApptID
        DisplayInfo()
    End If
```

The gvApptList.DataKeys(e.CommandArgument).Value always comes back as nothing.  What am I missing here?  I have this exact sale code working on other pages.

Comment: Don't you need to have the DataKeyName as a bound DataField?

Comment: Is AppointmentID included in your underlying SELECT query? Also, where is the DataSource and binding code? Best regards,

Comment: Yes, the Appointment ID is part of the data source, it loads from a class LeadAppointments that includes all appointment details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pertinent to your task, the correct syntax using `DataKeys` in ASP.NET `GridView` control is shown below (re: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/225352/Nesting-GridView-control-in-ASP-NET, written in C#):

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) 
{
   if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
   {
     // get data key from selected row
     s.SelectParameters[0].DefaultValue =Convert.ToString(((GridView)sender).DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Values["AppointmentID "]);
    }
}
```

You should obtain the reference to the `Row` corresponding to the command `Button` clicked, then extract the `DataKeys` value from that `Row`. Also, make sure that underlying `DataSource` contains `AppointmentID` field in its SELECT query.

Pertinent to your case it may look like the following (see Listing 2)

Listing 2.

```
protected void ViewButton_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = sender as Button;
    GridViewRow row = btn.NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
    string strID = gvApptList.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Values["AppointmentID"].ToString();

    int intID;
    if (String.IsNotNullOrEmpty(strID)
    {
      intID = int.Parse(strID);
    }
}
```

or you may use `TryParse()`, `Convert()`, etc.

Hope this may help.

Comment: I am not nesting the grid.  Is displays the appointment information human readable.

Comment: Nesting is irrelevant to your case, just refer to the core code snippet, and also please, include the entire code block for that event-handler you are using (Command Button Click). Best regards,